# ASP.NET MVC3 - ICollection editor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Given the following models

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class Trip
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have some info of what is the best way to achieve the following:

When I edit a trip, I would like to be able to add/remove persons.

Comment: Why not use List<Person>?

Answer (score 1):

The [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) interface defines methods for adding and removing items:

```
trip.Persons.Add(new Person { /* initialize */ });
```

And

```
trip.Persons.Remove(person);
```

When you call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, Entity Framework (I assume you use that) will add/remove the objects to/from the database.